# ScrollView and ListView in same xml layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, scrollview

I'd like to divide my layout screen into two parts:

- Half with a ScrollView
- Half with a ListView

Is it possible?

Thanks :)

Comment: yes it is. You just need to add a linearlayout (vertical). Then add a scrollview to it followed by a list. Just make sure that their heights are not fill parent or match parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Horizontally :   
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#192832" >
        </ScrollView>

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#193222" >
        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>

Vertically : 

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2" >

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#192832" >
        </ScrollView>

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#193222" >
        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>
```